# Hosting requirement: What does WCF need to work?

Tags: wcf

I plan to start developing with WCF this weekend. Before i get too far along, I'd like to know what I need from my web host? What does our server need to run to enable WCF? Is it standard ASP.NET 3.5 SP1 stuff? Does the host need to do anything to our IIS configuration?

I'm currently hosting our ASP.NET apps, company website, etc. with a third party hosting service. Due to our size, cost, etc. we are using a shared hosting plan and have somewhat limited access to chanign IIS. I'm hoping we don't have any problems that would limit our ability to use WCF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to host your WCF service in IIS, you need IIS6 (Win Server 2003) or preferably IIS7 (Win Server 2008), the .NET 3.0 (or preferably: .NET 3.5 SP1) framework, and the ability to create virtual directories in IIS (so yes, you need at least some degree of IIS configurability).

That's it! :-)

Marc

Comment: I would add that you can host WCF services in *any* .NET application, but I guess that when Scott says "what do I need from my web host", it means hosting the WCF service in IIS :)

Comment: @Philippe: absolutely true, but when using shared web hosting, this option might not be very viable.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

- **You can host in IIS6+ using ASP.NET:** simplest, offers integration with ASP.NET runtime (can be disabled to reduce overhead if not needed, imposes requirements on endpoint URLs, restricted to HTTP[S] as transport, all the benefits of IIS worker process management
- **You can host in IIS7+ using Windows Activation Services (WAS):** more advanced, complete control over endpoint URL, can use any transport (TCPIP, HTTP[S], MSMQ, NamedPipes), all the benefits of IIS worker process management
- **You can host in a custom Windows Service:** all the power of WAS except worker process management and you must write your own windows service and you have

For more information, check out [this section of the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx).